# I have a dropdown list in a GridView EditTemplate not saving the selection back to SQL

Tags: vb.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, .net-4.0, webforms

This is using a SQLDataSource.  I can see the choices and choosing one works, but then I click Update button it does not save anything. What am I missing?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                        Width="99px" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Status") %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem>Open</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Closed</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %  >'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You need to show the code on how you're saving the data.